# What is the minimum iOS version compatible with Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Our client's app is written in Object-C targeting some old iOS devices

We want to rewrite it with Swift 4.2

However I need official reference for Swift and iOS compatiblilty

As far as I know that Swift supports iOS 7 and above by doing StackOverflow search however I cannot find Apple or Swift.org reference regarding minimum iOS vetrsion for Swift 4.2

So I can show this to our client.

Comment: [This](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/94724) is the best I could find.

Comment: simple answer is `Language version is independent from iOS version`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2

It mentions iOS 7 as the earliest that would be compatible still.

Answer (score 1):

`Swift` is a language you write application in. It doesn't matter you write it in `Swift` or `Objective-C`, as when you build it in Xcode it is being compiled into machine language by way of llvm bit-code. So it means you can build app for any iOS that Xcode supports, min iOS version for your app is called Deployment Target. And can be set in project's general settings:[image]

At the time of writing latest Xcode is 10.1, which supports min deployment target of 8.0.